# prepositional phrases strong enough to bring 'the' before the nouns they modify?

Tags: prepositional-phrases

I was wondering if prepositional phrases alone were strong enough to bring the relative pronoun *the* before the nouns that they modify.

Upon reading (2) do you feel the *people* is restricted or specified with *the* because they are already mentioned before? Or, the sentence (2) standing alone, do you feel the *people* has *the* because of *in Japan*?

> 1. People in Japan speak Japanese.
> 2. The people in Japan speak Japanese.

Also, do you think my paraphrases are correct (is it wrong to use *that are* here)?

> 1. People in Japan speak Japanese. = People [that are] in Japan speak Japanese. = Probably many but not necessarily all the people [that are] in Japan speak Japanese.
> 2. The people in Japan speak Japanese. = The people [that are] in Japan speak Japanese. = All the people [that are] in Japan speak Japanese.

Comment: ** ** Yes. ** **

Comment: These are [generic noun phrases](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/000001.html). They're nearly identical, but the differences tend to be very specific to the context.

Comment: *People in Japan* (interpreted literally) could include visitors in Japan, who may not speak Japanese. What's wrong with *(The) Japanese people*?

Comment: Japanese speak Japanese.  French speak French.  Spanish speak Spanish.  Americans speak American-English.  Swedes speak Swedish.  Some Belgians speak Flemish.  Go figure!

Comment: @FumbleFingers, asterisks as filler to meet the minimum comment length? You should be ashamed for abusing the system like that. Everyone knows you're supposed to use [bananas](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/170699/bananas-in-comments) for this.

Comment: @Ben: Hmm. In BrE at least, it would be possible for me to have said *"Give the man a **coconut!**"* as an emphatic endorsement, but I'm not sure *"Give the man a **banana!**"* quite works. I didn't actually expect the asterisks to be visible - I thought the system would just display a couple of "bold" spaces before and after the only thing I really had to say. **Yes** (OP's paraphrasings are perfectly okay).

Comment: @rhetorician, I'm an American, yet I speak German.  Too.

Comment: @Cyberherbalist:  Question:  What do you call a person who speaks three languages?  Answer:  Trilingual. Question:  What do you call a person who speaks two languages?  Answer:  Bilingual.  Question:  What do you call a person who speaks one language?  Answer:  An American!

Answer (score 1):

Consider this pair: "Do people in Japan speak English?" (Yes, there are quite a few.) "Do the people in Japan speak English?" (No, the language of Japan is Japanese.)

English has quite a bit of ambiguity in it. "Speak" can mean either "able to speak" or "habitually speaks" and we choose based on context. Likewise "people" without "the" could mean all of them or it could mean just a subset. We often resolve ambiguity with a sort of internal dialogue where we ask ourselves "why did he/she just say that?" This part of linguistics is called *pragmatics*. (Pragmatics is the next level above semantics in the semiotic stack.)

So when someone asks "Do people in Japan speak Japanese?" We might marvel that someone could be that ignorant, but we'd have to conclude they're really asking what the language of Japan is. But when someone asks "Do people in Japan speak English," we *assume* that they know the language of Japan is Japanese, so they can't possibly be asking if *everyone* in Japan speaks English. We interpret it as asking if *anyone* in Japan speaks English.

When you say "the people" it leaves less room for ambiguity.

Answer (score 0):

The examples in your question are more than just prepositional phrases: they're full sentences (independent clauses).  Also, "the" is a definite article, not a relative pronoun.

The fact that something is a preposition phrase is not in itself a reason to include the definite article "the" in it.

If you mean "Japanese people" in both examples, whether or not you use the definite article makes no difference to the meaning.

If "people" includes others, the article could refer to a specific group in Japan, such as foreigners who speak Japanese.

More generally, as John Lawler points out, you need to think of the context whenever deciding to use the definite article in a preposition phrase.  If you want to know which kinds of preposition phrases include the *the* or tend to do so, you'll have to ask some more questions!